# Is there a poll in Germany on perceptions whether the antisemitism label is correctly used in the German political discourse?

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, germany, comparative-politics, antisemitism

I stumbled upon this [US poll](https://criticalissues.umd.edu/sites/criticalissues.umd.edu/files/UMCIP_Israel_Results_June2023.pdf) (conducted by U. of Maryland & Ipsos in June 2023) containing some questions on the public perceptions of the correct use of the antisemitism label, but also having some questions of its use for "delegitimization". (I found this while I was researching a different topic as the title of the poll document is just about Israel-Palestine, mind you):

> What is your impression of how labeling people antisemitic is used in the American political discourse:
>
> - Used to describe people who are genuinely antisemitic

More than half (58%) of the Democrats answered positively there (28%--frequently, 30%--sometimes) with 28% of them answering "I don't know" and 14%=11%+3% answered rather negatively ("not often" & "not at all"). Among Republicans it was slightly less than half (44%) who answered positively and with less strong agreement (13%--frequently, 31%--sometimes) with 34% "I don't know" and 21%=16%+5% answering "Not often"/"not at all".

There was were two subsequent questions on

- "Used to delegitimize political opponents", which while (IMHO) a bit ambiguously worded yielded a little bit of an inversion in answer splits in the strongest agreement bin ("frequently"). 52%=18%+34% of Democrats agreed with that statement ("frequently"/"sometimes") and 54%=25%+29% of Republicans agreed ("frequently"/"sometimes").
- "Used to delegitimize critics of Israel". This one oddly produced almost similar results among both political groups; around 52%=23%+29% of Democrats agreed it happened ("frequently"/"sometimes") and among Republicans it was 51%=21%+30%. There were identical splits from both groups on "I don't know"/"not often"/"not at all" 37%/8%/3%.

Original tabulation of the results given below:

[image]

I'm curious: is there a similar poll in Germany? (I could ask about other European countries, and maybe I will later on, but I would expect Germany to be a country where they'd take themselves most seriously on this topic. If there's somehow a EU-wide poll on something like this, it would be most informative, though.)

Comment: My first question about this poll is "frequently relative to what?"  For example, does answering question 16A "not often" indicate that I don't frequently hear "antisemitic" at all or that I hear it used frequently to describe someone who isn't genuinely antisemitic?  No wonder the "don't know" numbers are so high.

Comment: @phoog: yeah, I also had the impression the Qs in this poll were formulated a bit vaguely. I guess I could also ask if there's a more clear poll in the US, hmm...

Comment: The problem here is that ascribing the misuse of the term antisemitism _to the Jews_ is widely discussed in Germany as a form of [secondary antisemitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_antisemitism). Polls specifically ask about claims like this because it is assumed that people with antisemitic views [will hide behind indirect accusations](https://www.bpb.de/themen/rechtsextremismus/dossier-rechtsextremismus/262065/zur-verbreitung-des-antisemitismus-in-deutschland-empirische-forschungsbefunde-und-methodische-probleme/)...

Comment: ...When searching, these studies superimpose results, if they exist, that ask about the more general assessment of the political debate.

Comment: @ccprog That is already the third level. First there is calling people who are antisemitic antisemitic which I think everyone agrees on. Second there is the accusation that some people (Jewish or not) call any critique of the state of Israel antisemitic. You are describing the third level where Jewish people feel their use of the term antisemitic is delegitimized. I wonder whether the perceived prevalence of all the effects can be properly assessed by a poll.

Comment: There is an obvious problem with non-Jews discussing what Jews should consider offensive or not, men deciding what is good or bad for women, whites deciding for blacks, etc. One could even claim that the very idea that it is up to non-Jews to decide on the issues concerning Jews is antisemitism.

Comment: What really puts this poll into perspective is the other questions where people across the board profess an profound lack of knowledge about what antisemitism is in the first place. I mean 41% express that they don't think or don't know whether an anti-Jewish attitude is antisemitic. About 81% don't know or don't care what Zionism is. So in that context it's almost valid to ask what people think "antisemitism" means in the first place. I'd hope the German knowledge about that topic is better, though that would render these questions a lot more loaded and likely antisemitic.

Comment: I mean this is essentially asking how often people play the "antisemitism-card" of going for the ad hominem attack to deflect criticism or change topics. Insinuating this is a common thing. I mean the fact that you ask about it basically implies that at least that claim is made by someone... Where the "XYZ"-card, is already an "XYZ"-phobic concept meant to delegitimize valid criticism as outrage culture and unjustified exaggeration. And Roger V. has a point asking the majority about how offensive something is to minority is a dangerous concept because they likely don't witness most abuses.

Comment: Roger V.: I'm fine if answers only cover what German Jews said. But when it comes to polls, beggars can't be choosers, so I don't want to restrict the Q too much. I'm not sure how pollsters in Germany would approach this topic. (IIRC you kinda objected to how Israeli polling firms divide their subjects [just] between Jews and Arabs though.)